# Passing items from two related tables through foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, foreach

I have two tables on the database, the seccond of which with items refering to table 1.
I’m passing the items from table_1 onto a view through a foreach loop, and I’d like to include on each of those items a list of the related items from table_2, whenever they exist.

How could I do that:

```
id_table_1 | item_table_1
---------- | ------------
1          | item 1
2          | item 2
3          | item 3

id_table_2 | item_table_2 | id_table_1
-----------|--------------|-----------
1          | pic 1        | 1
2          | pic 2        | 1
3          | pic 3        | 1
4          | pic 4        | 2
5          | pic 5        | 3
```

The Controller:

```
function view()
    {
            $data['main_content'] = 'things';
$this->load->model('main_model');
            $data['items'] = $this->main_model->get_items();
            $this->load->view('includes/template', $data); }
```

The Model:

```
function get_items($id_geral) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM table_1");
        return $query->result();
    }
```

The view:

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>id_table_1</th>
    <th>item_table_1</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach ($items as $items) {
    echo ‘
        <tr>
        <td>’.$item->id_table_1.’</td>
        <td>’.$item→item_table_1.’</td>
        </tr>’;
        } ?>
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I have no ideas
I thought about doing something like:

`SELECT table_1.*, table_2.* FROM table_1, table_2 WHERE table_2.id_table_1=table_1.id_table_1`

but then I'd get as many times the same item from table_1 as the number of items from table_2 related to it, and I'd want to echo each item from table_1 a single time...

Answer (score 1):

You can join table 1 and table2 in model getItems() function. Like:

The Model:

```
function get_items($id_geral) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT table1.*, id_table_2, item_table_2 FROM table_1 LEFT JOIN table_2 WHERE table_1.id_table_1=table_2.id_table_1");
    return $query->result();
}
```

The view:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>id_table_1</th>
<th>item_table_1</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach ($items as $items) {
echo ‘
    <tr>
    <td>’.$item->id_table_1.’</td>
    <td>’.$item→item_table_1.’</td>
    <td>’.$item->id_table_2.’</td>
    <td>’.$item→item_table_2.’</td>
    </tr>’;
    } ?>
```

Comment: Maybe I've simplified it too much, since I'm already linking other tables on the model. How would I do that if on my model I'd have

`function get_descritivo_analises($id_geral) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT table_1.*, table_3.*, table_4.*, (SELECT COUNT(id_table_2) FROM table_2 WHERE table_2.id_table_1=table_1.id_table_1) AS contagem FROM table_1, table_3, table_4 WHERE table_1.id_table_4=table_4.id_table_4 AND table_1.id_table_Xl='" . $id_geral . "' AND table_1.id_table_3=table_3.id_table_3");
        return $query->result();
    }`

Comment: the question you asked has been answered here. If you have another quetion please post a new question and please do avoid dhit table1, table2, x,y, nonsense and post real tables

Comment: @Baya Did you get your answer?